# Although there are straight and circling minimums in the VOR Z chart, why separate VOR A chart created containing only the circle-to-land minimum?

Tags: iaps, vor, circling-approach

Although there are straight-in-landing and circle-to-land minimums in the VOR Z chart, why was a separate VOR A chart created containing only the circle-to-land minimum? When we examine the chart images of Çorlu airport that I have shared below, although there are circle-to-land values at the bottom right of the VOR Z Rwy 04 chart, a separate VOR A chart was created using only these values. I don't understand why a separate VOR A chart was created specifically for these minimums, although there is already a chart where these values are specified. To be able to fly without using DME or just to perform a visual descent? I already know that only circle-to-land minimums are used in VOR A, B, C.. charts, but I am not sure what the reason for a separate VOR A chart is for this airport, I would appreciate your help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only relevant difference I can see is

> 1. DME required.

for the **VOR Z** approach. The **VOR A** does not have such a requirement. This allows aircraft without DME to fly the VOR approach.

Note how the outbound leg from the VOR is flown differently. On the **VOR Z** you fly out to a DME of 7.0 before turning back in (even when later flying a circle-to-land):

[image: VOR Z]

On the **VOR A** the outbound leg is a timed leg of 2 or 3 minutes depending on the aircraft approach category:

[image: VOR A]

Since this is less accurate, the platform altitude was also increased from 2000 to 2300 feet, probably to ensure sufficient terrain clearance when ending up further out than 7 NM for the turn.

Comment: I would like to ask a question that is on my mind. It's normal for the minimum to change due to approach requirements, but why are these minimums published as circle-to-land minimums? Why isn't it published as straight-in landing minimums? I'm wondering what makes the difference here. Because, despite no reason, circle-to-land minimum values are published on VOR A, B, and C charts. Why isn't it published as a straight-in landing?